# SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument; __init__ related

Tags: python

This is my last resort. I've searched everywhere, but it's always pertaining to it being re-written by another function or something. I assure you there is no other function that uses this **init** thing. I'm a beginner.

The error is that I get this: SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument. It points towards `__init__([here]self, ...etcetc)`.

```
class book:

def __init__(self, bookId, nextBook=None, name, author, ageGroup):
    self.bookId = bookId
    self.nextBook = nextBook
    self.name = str(name)
    self.author = str(author)
    self.ageGroup = str(ageGroup)

def getInfo(self):
    return self.bookdId

def setInfo(self, bookId, bookName, authorName, ageGroup):
    self.bookId = bookId
    self.name = bookName
    self.author = authorName
    self.ageGroup = ageGroup

def getNextBook(self):
    return self.nextBook

def setNextBook(self,val):
    self.nextBook = val

class bookCollection:

def __init__(self,head = None):
    self.head = head
    self.size = 0

def getSize(self):
    return self.size

def addBookToFront(self,bookId):
    newBook = book(bookId,self.head)
    self.head = newBook
    self.size+=1
    return True

def listAllBooks(self):
    curr = self.head
    while curr:
        print(curr.data)
        print(curr.name)


        curr = curr.getNextBook()

def deleteBook(self,value):
    prev = None
    curr = self.head
    while curr:
        if curr.getInfo() == value:
            if prev:
                prev.setNextBook(curr.getNextBook())
            else:
                self.head = curr.getNextBook()
            return True     
        prev = curr
        curr = curr.getNextBook()  
    return False

def addBookAtPosition(self, newBookId, position):
    counter = 1

    if position == 0:
        newBookId.setNextBook(self.head)
        self.head = newBookId

    else:
        book = self.head
        while book.getNextBook() is not None:
            if counter == position:
                newBookId.setNextBook(book.getNextBook())
                book.setNextBook(newBookId)
            book = book.getNextBook()
            counter = counter + 1

def removeBookAtPosition(self, removedBookId, position):
    counter = 1

    if position == 0:
        self.head = removedBookId.getNextBook()

    else:
        book = self.head
        while book.getNextBook() is not None:
            if counter == position - 1:
                book.setNextBook(removedBookId.getNextBook())

            book = book.getNextBook()
            counter = counter + 1

 #for reference: bookId, bookName, authorName, ageGroup
 Boy = book(1, Boy, Roald-Dahl, Teens)
```

Comment: I don't know what your search results looked like, but that was literally the first google hit for `non-default argument follows default argument` when I searched. The error message is also pretty explicit about what's wrong.

Comment: I did mention I'm a beginner, so that particular qn did not make sense to me, much less the error message. Due to my limited knowledge, i didn't see anything wrong with the asker's code, reading the top answer made no sense to me. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining about this line:

```
def __init__(self, bookId, nextBook=None, name, author, ageGroup):
```

Argument *nextBook* has a default value, namely None.
But arguments *name*, *author* and *ageGroup* don't have default values.
That is prohibited by the interpreter, or, more exact, by the parser part of the interpreter.

Either don't give *nextBook* a default value, or give default values also for *name*, *author* and *ageGroup*. If you want a default value only for *nextBook*, make it the last parameter, so after *name*, *author* and *ageGroup*.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now, thanks. I didn't realise it has to be the last, the other qn an anonymous user marked this qn a duplicate (which after understanding, true it is quite similar) was worded too advancedly, thanks for making it simple :)